# Isolation transformer isolation side earthing best practices

Tags: transformer, grounding, earth, isolated

I have been told I need my equipment to be isolated, but I want to make sure I fully understand when an isolation transformer is no longer **isolated**. The equipment I have clearly has an earth ground, but I am not sure how to wire it to protect the end equipment.

I have read conflicting information on how to best connect my protective earth on the isolation side of a transformer.

Coming off my main I have 1 phase 240 converted to 3 phase 240. The 3 phase is then fed into an isolation transformer. Do I need to avoid linking both sides of the transformers earth together?

Said another way:

- do I ground the transformer chassis with the main 240 ground + neutral. then have the isolated side of the transformer's earth connected directly into a dedicated grounding rod that only services the transformers output? **(First Image)**
- or can I have a continuous earth from the main power supply to both sides of the transformer (such that I would have conductivity from the main panel to the sensitive equipment chassis). **(Second Image)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need an isolation transformer? Without understanding your goal, it is very hard to offer meaningful advice.

Comment: I believe the isolation transformer was recommended because I am using a rotary phase converter or because of the sensitivity of the electronics.